# Does having a known suffix on the input to PBKDF2 make you more vulnerable?

Tags: sha-1, pbkdf-2, collision-attack

I have an implementation of PBKDF2, which I know

- Has two bytes of '=' at the end of the input
- Has an input length of 24 (which is a Base64 encoded character representation of 16 bytes of entropy)
- Uses one iteration
- Has a known 9-character salt.

It's using a SHA1 hasher.

Does knowing the two `=` bytes at the end of input (which represent the base64 encoding for padding) reduce the complexity of finding all possible collisions for a 24 characters input?

Just to clarify,

```
password = "24_characters_ends_in_==";
key = sha1_pkbdf2_hmac( password, KNOWN_SALT, 1 );
```

Does knowing two characters at the end of the password further increase the ability to find collisions?

Answer (score 1):

> Does knowing the two = bytes at the end of input (which represent the base64 encoding for padding) reduce the complexity of finding all possible collisions for a 24-character input?

Since you pre-processed the users' password with base64, then the base64 may need padding. Depending on the input, base64 may add none, one, or two equal (`=`) characters. [In short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples), base64 processes the input with 24-bit blocks, and

- if the last 24 bit is full i.e. 3 ASCII characters, then no padding
- if the last 24 bit contains only two characters then two zeros with one `=`
- if the last 24 bit contains only one character then four zeros with two `=`

  is appended. Using these rules, one can reverse the base64 padding.

This padding is not part of your password, so **the entropy of your input doesn't change** since base64 is reversible - **neither reduces the entropy nor increases**. The attacker still needs to work your actual password space.

Even the salt will not increase the entropy, it only reduces the attacker's capabilities by eliminating the Rainbow Tables.

> Does knowing two characters at the end of the password further increase the ability to find collisions?

Collision are not related to password security, you need the second pre-image attack

- **Second Pre-image attack:** given a message $m_1$ find another message $m_2$ such that $m_1 \neq m_2$ and $Hash(m_1)=Hash(m_2)$.
- **Collision attack** : find two inputs that hash to the same output $a$ and $b$ such that $H(a)= H(b)$, $a \neq b.$

As we can see, a collision has nothing to do with the passwords. The second per-image does since the attacker sees the password hash then it tries to find one that works with the given password hash ( with the salt and the iteration).

The confusion may come from the fact that these two inputs are collisions, however, the terminology must not be used in this way. Assume that I found two colliding pairs of hashes then, this will work with the given password hash, NO!

---

**A note on the iteration:**

Currently, the iteration count is set to 1. This is not good. One needs to use as much as possible to reduce that attacker's capabilities, so set the iteration count like 100K or 1M. Remember that the higher the count, the more time the user will wait. The current practice is not letting users wait more than one second. You can see some in-use iteration examples in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2#Purpose_and_operation)

Answer (score 0):

If the password is exactly 24 characters long with a static "==" at the end, it does effectively reduce the search space to 22 characters, as any password without the "==" is invalid and would not be attempted.

Comment: These are not part of the original password, it comes from base64 encoding and that is reversible. See in my answer.